# request.security() returns a copy of an object, unlike other functions - correct?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Based on the script below I conclude that, unlike normal functions, `request.security()` returns a copy of an object passed to a function called from it. Am I correct?

You can pass an object to a normal function `f1(obj)`, it is passed as a reference, and you can get back that same reference from it. But you can't do the same with `request.security(..., f1(obj))`

I hoped that since objects are passed by reference I can create a huuuge var object, store there all I need and pass a reference to it all around my functions. Looks that is not the case.

Also, how can value of `hRs2.s` become `"333 hRs2 changed"` before it get assigned this value, and only on some (!!!) of the candles (please see the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oqBJ.jpg)

The script (run it on 3M BTCUSDT.P Bybit chart):
The screenshot: https://www.tradingview.com/x/ut1mh3ay/

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © moebius1977

// RUN THIS ON 3M CHART (e.g. BTCUSDT.P Bybit)
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay =  true)

type hh
    string  s

f1(hh _h) =>
    _h.s := "222 from f1()"
    _h


// ====== CHART's TF ======
h1 = hh.new("111 orig")

h2 = f1(h1)
sOver = "h1.s: " + h1.s + "\nh2.s: " + h2.s

h2.s := "333 h2 changed"
sOver := sOver +  "\n------\n" + "h1.s: " + h1.s + "\nh2.s: " + h2.s

lblOver = label.new(bar_index, high, sOver, style = label.style_label_down, color = color.rgb(217, 252, 162))

// ====== HTF ======

hRs1 = hh.new("111 hRs orig")
 
hRs2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "6M", f1(hRs1))  
// next line changes hRs2, but not hRs1 - how? 
// Means that unlike normal functions, request.security creates and returns a copy of an object received as argument.  
hRs2 := na(hRs2) ? hh.new("hRs is na") : hRs2
sUnder =  "hRs1.s: " + hRs1.s + "\nhRs2.s: " + hRs2.s

hRs2.s := "333 hRs2 changed"
sUnder := sUnder +  "\n------\n" + "hRs1.s: " + hRs1.s + "\nhRs2.s: " + hRs2.s

lblRsUnder = label.new(bar_index, low, sUnder , style = label.style_label_up, color = color.rgb(151, 255, 245))



plotchar(false, "", "", location.bottom)
```

Answer (score 0):

From support: "the call of the security function creates an independent chart of the requested timeframe/symbol and calculates a given expression in the scope of this chart, it cannot change variables from the scope of the main chart, but only returns the result of calculations."